# Mallocing and Freeing in C, but passing the pointer through Python via ctypes

Tags: python, c, pointers, ctypes

I would like to put a `malloc` a function in C. I would then like to call this function from Python 3.10 via `ctypes.DLL`. I then would like to `free` it.

However, I get a segmentation fault. Here's my very simple C code:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

struct QueueItem {
    void *value;
    struct QueueItem *next;
};

struct Queue {
    struct QueueItem* head;
    struct QueueItem* tail;
};

struct Queue * new_queue(void * value) {
    struct Queue* queue = malloc(sizeof(struct Queue));

    struct Queue queue_ = { value, NULL };

    return queue;
}

void delete_queue(struct Queue* queue) {
    free(queue);
};
```

I'll compile this with `gcc -fPIC -shared src/queue.c -o queue.so`, and thenn on the python side:

```py
import ctypes

queue = ctypes.CDLL("./queue.so")

q = ctypes.POINTER(queue.new_queue(1))
print(q)
print(type(q))

queue.delete_queue(q)
```

But running this will yield:

```
-1529189344
<class 'int'>
Segmentation fault
```

The question is, **how do I malloc in C, pass the pointer through python, and then free it again in C?**.

**Primary Resources Consulted:**

- [Passing pointer to DLL via Ctypes in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620350/passing-pointer-to-dll-via-ctypes-in-python)
- [Python Ctypes passing pointer to structure containing void pointer array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31007712/python-ctypes-passing-pointer-to-structure-containing-void-pointer-array)
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html
- Messing around with ctypes.POINTER but it complains about types, and I'm not an expert in this area.

Comment: You need to declare the return type properly (as a `c_void_p` at the least, or a properly defined pointer type). The default return type for `ctypes` imported functions is `int`, which, on a 64 bit system, is half the required width. You can't just go calling the function without defining the `restype` attribute on it properly and casting the result. The `delete_queue` call might not *need* `argtypes` defined (if you pass it a `c_void_p`, I believe it'll assume that's what it's supposed to pass), but you should still do it for safety.

Comment: I didn't even notice that the int was half the size I wanted. Ah, got it, if you (or someone) wants to make an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate of [\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't define the `restype` and `argtypes` for a function, the `restype` is assumed to be a C `int` (`c_int`), and the argument types are guessed at based on what you pass. The problem here is that the implicit `restype` of C `int` is (on a 64 bit system) half the width of a pointer, so the value returned by `new_queue` is only half of a pointer (which is completely useless).

For safety, and error-checking, you should define both before calling a function, especially the `restype` which can't be inferred.

So for your code, you might do:

```
import ctypes

queue = ctypes.CDLL("./queue.so")

queue.new_queue.argtypes = (c_void_p,)
queue.new_queue.restype = c_void_p

queue.delete_queue.argtypes = (c_void_p,)
queue.delete_queue.restype = None

q = queue.new_queue(1)
print(q)
print(type(q))

queue.delete_queue(q)
```

Note that passing along `1` as the argument to `new_queue` is almost certainly incorrect, but I suspect it will work here since none of the code will actually try to use it.

Comment: I want to use it eventually, what should I use instead? I want to pass in arbitrary objects eventually.

Comment: @npengra317: Well, one, you need to describe what you want. You're passing an `int` to something that accepts a `void*`. That means, by default, Python passes along the numeric value as a pointer address (it's a pointer to memory address 0x1, which is almost always unusable for dereferencing). You can create actual `c_int`s and pass their `ctypes.pointer(c_int_instance)` or the like. You can change `new_queue`'s return type and `delete_queue`'s argtype to the `ctype.POINTER` of a custom `ctypes.Structure`. Or write Cython extensions, raw C extensions, or use interface generators like SWIG.